# Intel i5 520-M and Ubuntu 15.10 amdx64 is it compatible?

Tags: 15.10

I have a laptop with 4 GB RAM and CPU Intel i5 520-M it's a x64 bits processor in the specification. Is Ubuntu 15.10 amd64 ISO image compatible for this CPU, or only i386? Because the system starts quite slow. Help me until I install all software I need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu is fully compatible with x86_64 CPUs.

Ubuntu probably boots slowly due to the HDD's I/O speed.

Could you run a read benchmark from the included Disks application?

Comment: I receved this message when I tried to do the test. "Error unmounting /dev/sda1: Command-line `umount  "/dev/sda1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: umount: /: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
 (udisks-error-quark, 14)" System boots slower but seems to work stable.

Comment: When I unclicked the average speed read is 62,4 MB/s (100 samples)